# How to get window position on Android or the keyboard height?

Tags: python, android, position, kivy

How do I get the position of my window on Android when the window is shifted upward because

```
softinput_mode = "pan".
```

I need to know the position in-other to re-adjust the position of my widgets so that they can be seen by the user because whenever the keyboard is requested by the user, the window is shifted upward and some of my widgets that are top-mid cannot be seen by the user.

Comment: if there is really no way or an hack to get the keyboard height or the new position of the window when it is shifted upwards how then do you expect people to make a good application with kivy? ugh?

Comment: I don't think we support this at the moment, although possibly there is some in progress code that needs linking together.